# TeeChart change distance between axis title and axis DELPHI XE3

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have chart where at the bottom axis dates are shown. The date string I have splitted into two lines. In the first is the date and in the second is the time. My problem is now, that the labels and the axis title are overlapping -> see image:

[image: Issue: Title and label overlapping]

I googled for a while but found no solution or option I can use to set the distance between the axis title and the axis. The property
`TChart.MarginBottom` only changes the margin between the plotting area and component border. I have tried different properties to set the title vertical position:

```
// chtData is of type TChart
chtData.BottomAxis.Title.VertTextAlign := TVertTextAlign.vtaBottom; // Did not change anything
chtData.BottomAxis.Title.Margins.Top := 20; // Did not change anything
```

Is there any property I do not see?

Thank in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no automatic calculation of labels' height

Seattle TChart:

in Obj. Inspector: `BottomAxis - Labels - LabelSize  set value 32`

in chart editor: `Axis - BottomAxis - Labels - Style - Size`

in code: `Chart.BottomAxis.LabelsSize := 2 * UsualValue`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You have to change the size of the labels to shift the caption down. Dynamically it can be done by `chtData.BottomAxis.LabelsSize := 2 *  chtData.BottomAxis.LabelsSize`.